# Can't insert new row to database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$q5 = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE name='$sn'";

$r5 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q5);

if($r5) {


        $q3 = "UPDATE subjects SET grade='$grade' WHERE name='$sn'";

        $r3 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q3);

} else {

        echo "false";
        //$q3 = "INSERT INTO subjects (name, grade) VALUES ('$sn', '$grade')";

        //$r3 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q3);

}

create_subject_table($sn, $assignment, $assignment_max, $dbc);

}
```

In a beginning I am checking if that row already exist. If it does I use query to update it, if not it supposed to insert new one. My problem is that $r5 always true. So it updates normally, but doesn't insert anything. I tried to echo false to make sure that my query is right, and I don't see it. Can someone help me, please. I spent few hours on this problem and can't figure it out...

Comment: I don't know php well enough to know exactly, but I expect you need to do something like get the count of the $r5 value and use that as your condition. Also note that if $sn is something the user controls, you have a classic SQL exploit on your hands.  (Insert obligatory xkcd cartoon on bobby tables)

Comment: Thanks, I heard about SQL injections, but I am not very familiar with them. I'll definetly check it out to improve my security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `mysqi_query` will return `false` if the query fails for some and an object/true if it succeeds. In this case, it'll return an object with nothing in it.

What you want to do instead of checking for true, you want to do something like:

```
if ($r5->num_rows > 0)
```

instead of

```
if ($r5)
```

as the first will only pass if you actually get a result back from the DB, and not just that the query didn't throw an error.

From the PHP doc page for [mysqi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept my solution then on SO. :D

Comment: Elegant use of result object notation, like it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to find out if there is a certain row.

Method one counts the number of matching rows with SQL:

```
$q5 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_subjects FROM subjects WHERE name='$sn'";
$r5 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q5);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r5);

if ($row['number_of_subjects'] > 0) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Method two counts the number of the result set with `mysqli_num_rows`:

```
$q5 = "SELECT * AS number_of_subjects FROM subjects WHERE name='$sn'";
$r5 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q5);

$number = mysqli_num_rows($r5);

if ($number) {
   ...
} else 
   ...
}
```